# TO_CHAR and TO_DATE giving different results.How to achieve the TO_CHAR functionality using TO_DATE?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting, to-date, to-char

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((select logical_date -1 from logical_date 
where logical_date_type='B'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

This Query returns `23/04/2016 00:00:00`

```
o/p of select logical_date -1 from logical_date where logical_date_type='B' :4/23/2016

SELECT TO_DATE((select logical_date -1 from logical_date 
where logical_date_type='B'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

This Query returns `4/23/0016`.

How do I get the format given by TO_CHAR using TO_DATE ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dates do not have any intrinsic format. Oracle has an internal representation which doesn't look like anything you'd recognise as a date. The client or application decides how to display the date (e.g. using NLS_DATE_FORMAT), or you can use `TO_CHAR` to convert the date to a string with a format you specify, as you're doing in your first example.

In your second example you are doing an implicit comversion of your actual date to a string, using your NLS setting - losing the century in the process, so presumably that has YY rather than YYYY - and then you convert that back to a date. I'm surprised that doesn't error as you are swapping the month and day positions.

Do not do that. Converting to a string and back to a date is pointless, even if your settings don't lose information on the way.

If you want it as a date for a client or other process to use just do:

```
select logical_date -1
from logical_date 
where logical_date_type='B'
```

If you want to compare against another date then still leave it as a date:

```
select other_columns
from logical_date 
where logical_date_type='B'
and logical_date -1 < sysdate
```

If you want to specify the format **for display** then use:

```
select to_char(logical_date -1, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
from logical_date 
where logical_date_type='B'
```

Comment: Actually the stored bytes are still readable: http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/date_representation.htm.

Comment: I want to compare it with sysdate ('DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') in where clause so how do i implement it with TO_DATE() instead of TO_CHAR()

Comment: @Husqvik - I didn't say it isn't readable, just that the OP wouldn't recognise it as a date. I didn't think going into more detail about how to see it via dump or how to interpret that would help the OP at this point *8-)

Comment: @Rishi - they are both dates, so compare tham as dates. SYSDATE is being shown in that format *by your client*. Don't convert either of them to strings.

Comment: @Husqvik The whole point of **format mask** is to make the byte data readable, since a non-oracle guy won't understand the internal format :-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to the default date format for your session that is configured in your oracle client settings
To check the NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings for your Session

```
SELECT value
FROM   nls_session_parameters
WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
```

here's how you can change this setting for your session to achieve the desired results:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Comment: This assumes the OP will always be able to control the environment where the query will run; it's better to not rely on the NLS setting at all really. It also leaves them doing the unnecessary conversin to a string and back in the second example.

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, 
I aggree... Assuming that you're writing application code, you should avoid relying on NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings and use TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I get the format given by TO_CHAR using TO_DATE ?

Firstly, **DATE** doesn't have any format. Oracle does not store dates in the format you see. It stores it internally in **7 bytes** with each byte storing different components of the d**atetime** value.

```
Byte    Description
----    -------------------------------------------------
1       Century value but before storing it add 100 to it
2       Year and 100 is added to it before storing
3       Month
4       Day of the month
5       Hours but add 1 before storing it
6       Minutes but add 1 before storing it
7       Seconds but add 1 before storing it
```

The **format** is only for **display** purpose. **TO_DATE** is used to convert a literal into date, and has nothing to do with formatting. To display a date in your desired format, use **TO_CHAR**  with proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

Also, remember, formatting has an **order of precedence**:

Let's see the **chronological order of precedence**, i.e. starting from highest to least:

- Using **TO_CHAR** or **TO_DATE** at the **individual SQL statement**
- `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=’whatever format model you want’;`
- Setting it as an **OS environment variable** on the **client machine**
- Setting of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is in the **database initialization parameters**

For example,

**Individual SQL statement:**

```
SQL> SELECT HIREDATE, TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM emp;

HIREDATE            TO_CHAR(HI
------------------- ----------
17/12/1980 00:00:00 1980-12-17
20/02/1981 00:00:00 1981-02-20
22/02/1981 00:00:00 1981-02-22
02/04/1981 00:00:00 1981-04-02
28/09/1981 00:00:00 1981-09-28
01/05/1981 00:00:00 1981-05-01
09/06/1981 00:00:00 1981-06-09
09/12/1982 00:00:00 1982-12-09
17/11/1981 00:00:00 1981-11-17
08/09/1981 00:00:00 1981-09-08
12/01/1983 00:00:00 1983-01-12
03/12/1981 00:00:00 1981-12-03
03/12/1981 00:00:00 1981-12-03
23/01/1982 00:00:00 1982-01-23

14 rows selected.
```

**Session level:**

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT hiredate FROM emp;

HIREDATE
----------
1980-12-17
1981-02-20
1981-02-22
1981-04-02
1981-09-28
1981-05-01
1981-06-09
1982-12-09
1981-11-17
1981-09-08
1983-01-12
1981-12-03
1981-12-03
1982-01-23

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

> TO_DATE((select logical_date

This is wrong.

Never apply **TO_DATE** on a **DATE** column. It forces Oracle to:

- first convert it into a string
- then convert it back to date

based on the **locale-specific NLS settings**. You need **TO_DATE** to convert a literal into date. For **date-arithmetic**, leave the date as it is.