# Cannot Truncate date from table

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query returns:

```
select logical_date from logical_date;    
4/24/2016
```

On using TRUNC() I get

```
SELECT TRUNC(select logical_date from logical_date) 
FROM DUAL;

ORA-00936: missing expression
```

logical_date gives only date not time

Comment: `SELECT TRUNC(logical_date) from logical_date`?

Comment: Why the subquery? Why not just select the truncated date straight from your table? And your column does have a time, even if it is midnight and/or your client is not showing it. This s affected by your NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which was mentioned in the answers to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35309702/266304). I'm not sure what result you're expecting.

Comment: If you have a table called `logical_date` with only one record containing a column called `logical_date`, why do you have to truncate at all? Why isn't this a mere date (i.e. already truncated) in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DATE` always has a date and a time component - sometimes the client interface will be setup to only display part of the data (i.e. only the date component).

The `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` determines how your date is formatted. You can find out the current format with the query:

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

In your case it appears that the format mask is set to `MM/DD/YYYY`.

You can change the date format using:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

(or whatever format mask you wish to use).

Then you can do

```
select logical_date from logical_date;
```

which will output something like:

```
24-APR-2016 11:22:33
```

or

```
select TRUNC( logical_date ) from logical_date;
```

which will output:

```
24-APR-2016 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to use this is what jarlh suggested in comments like this

```
SELECT TRUNC(logical_date) from logical_date
```

**But** if you **absolutely** want to use it the way you want, then use something like this

```
SELECT TRUNC((select logical_date from logical_date)) as logical_date 
FROM DUAL;
```